# How to run an executable automatically Ubuntu 14

Tags: startup, ubuntu-14.04

I aware that this is a common theme but I can not find anything what I can use. I have a .cpp code in which I can see the video from a Ipcamera. I am working with Ubuntu 14. I compile the code in the Terminal like this:

```
g++ ipcamera.cpp -o camera `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

and it finish ok, and I got a executable "camera" which I can run without problem, it seems that everything works propertly, and I can see the video without problem.

The thing is that I want that this executable start automatically when ubuntu starts, I have been reading in many forum but nothing works for me. I guees that is because I need the GUI for run this executable, but I do not know how to do this.

Someone can help me?

Many thanks

Comment: I suggest you look into [cron](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), or [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com)

Comment: Thanks auisdante could you be more specific? and, I can not do this with init.d?

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this thread is ancient, and that it is concerning Ubuntu 14, whereas my answer is for Linux Mint 17.  I successfully added an executable from the Windows Partition (on my dual boot system) to be ran upon startup of Mint.  Open the Mint Menu, type "Session and Startup".  Go to the Application Autostart tab, hit the Add button, then you can hit the folder icon to the right of the Command section, navigate to the executable that you want to automatically launch, and choose it.  Hit OK, then Close, and you're done.  Hope that this helps somebody.